# Errors when test rails functionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Hi I get the following errors when I am testing the functional parts of my app, basically the tests runs but I get these errors which I don't know what it is referring to.

```
AdminControllerTest:
ERROR should get index (0.13s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<AdminControllerTest:0x007fe9e0119000>      /Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack- 3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'


CartsControllerTest:
ERROR should create cart (0.12s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9de592b10>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'

ERROR should destroy cart (0.17s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9de3569a0>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-   3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'

ERROR should get edit (0.12s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9e10c19d0>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'

ERROR should get index (0.11s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9e10604f0>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'

ERROR should get new (0.11s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9e1033fe0>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'

ERROR should show cart (0.11s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9e10109c8>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'

ERROR should update cart (0.12s) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `carts' for #<CartsControllerTest:0x007fe9de460558>
/Users/@@@@@/Dropbox/blind/rack/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'
```

carts controller test
    require 'test_helper'

```
class CartsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
setup do
@cart = carts(:one)
end

test "should get index" do
get :index
assert_response :success
assert_not_nil assigns(:carts)
end

test "should get new" do
get :new
assert_response :success
end

test "should create cart" do
assert_difference('Cart.count') do
post :create, cart: @cart.attributes
end

assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:cart))
end

test "should show cart" do
get :show, id: @cart
assert_response :success
end

test "should get edit" do
get :edit, id: @cart
assert_response :success
end
```

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Post your admin or carts controller test.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's having problems loading the fixtures. It can't figure out how to resolve the `carts` method in your `setup` definition.

Did you set them up in your `test/fixtures/` directory?

See the [rails testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) for info on how to set them up properly, but I'm guessing you want something like this:

`test/fixtures/carts.yml`:

```
one:
  name: bork
  foo_attribute: bar_value
two:
  name: other_cart
  foo_attribute: blah_value
```

Comment: I will have a look at my fixtures now and get back to you about that

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have created the test database.

Comment: I have set up the fixtures ymls but I still get the same error when I try to test.

Comment: This answer is poorly worded. Did you mean "check you have created the test database"?